# Missing 'strcasestr.cpp' file when compiling Tesseract 3.03 training tools

Tags: makefile, ocr, tesseract, autoconf

I have managed to build the `Tesseract 3.03 rc1` from source. But when I try to build the training tools, which is the very feature I want form 3.03, I got the following error.

[image]

It seems there should be a `strcasestr.cpp` file at the `vs2010` folder. But the downloaded source only contains the below files:

[image]

The command I used is:

```
make training
```

And I followed the instruction to build `Tesseract 3.03 rc1` first before building the training tools.

Anyone could shed some light?

### ADD 1

Found this thread:
https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=1458

Some quote:

> 1. Training is not supported on windows.
> 2. If you want to test/fix something, use the current code from repository (it should be posible to build it with msys2 on windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to build tesseract on windows (including the training tools) by using this git repository : https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract-vs2012

It's targetting vs2013 but with some modifications it works perfectly for vs2010.

If you don't want to rebuild everything, you only need to look at the

> vs2013+64bit_support.patch

file. It creates strcasestr.(h/cpp), gettimeofday.(h/cpp), strtok_r.(h/cpp) and mathifix.h which are the files you are missing.

Hope it help.

Comment: Thanks!  I am using Xubuntu to build the `tesseract 3.03.03` now. I will try your solution later. Again, thanks!